# generate sequilize models from sql file

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, import.sql

I am building a nodejs API with PostgreSQL & Sequilize. My client gave me a .sql file which has been exported from dbdiagram.io.

Is it possible to generate all my models base on .sql file ?

or do I have to do it all manually ?

Comment: https://github.com/ozum/pg-generator

Answer (score 1):

**Sequelize-auto** can automatically create model file (its a npm package).

You need to have a database created using the SQL file and then use `sequelize-auto.`

It automatically generate models for SequelizeJS via the command line.

**Installation:**

```
npm install -g sequelize-auto
```

**Using command line :**

```
sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d sequelize_auto_test -h localhost -u my_username -p 5432 -x my_password -e postgres
```

[Sequelize-auto npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto)

Comment: thanks, but got an error connection.query(...).on is not a function

Comment: there is real code, I simply create a table manually then try the command line. I endup manually create each model.